# Are the XLL Excel Add-ins developed with Excel 2007 SDK portable on Windows systems without .net runtime?

Tags: excel, xll

I plan on developing Excel Add-ins and I have looked around on ways of getting it accomplished. What I have found from expert views on various forums whom suggest using third party XLL development environments (XLW, ExcelDNA and host of others) instead of Excel SDK development 2007 with C++ as the latter option requires steep learning curve and for novices such as me would require managing low level details such as memory management

So my question is whether the XLL produced or developed using the 3rd party tools (XLW,  ExcelDNA) would run on users Windows system that do not have .net runtime support. There are only 1 or 2 sample tutorials on the web about development of XLL with Excel 2007 SDK using Visual Studio.net and users comments on those tutorials suggest that an XLL developed in Visual Studio.net using Excel 2007 SDK are not runnable on Windows that do not have .net runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you develop your add-in with C# or VB.NET (either with Excel-DNA or XLW), it will require the .NET runtime to be present on the client machines. If you develop the add-in with C++ (with XLW or another C+-based toolkit like XLL+) your add-in will not require the .NET runtime.

Answer (score 0):

By default XLW uses the dynamically linked C runtime so you need to be sure the target machine has the appropriate version. http://xll.codeplex.com uses static linking so you can be sure your xll will run on any Windows machine.